# Background cut vertically on iphone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, background

I'm having trouble understanding why the background of my webpage is cut on iphone. See for yourself http://www.zananda.fr. It's a wordpress page with homemade template.
I searched in here to find an answer, but I don't think this problem has been asked already.
Thank you very much for your help.
Emmanuelle

Comment: Have you tried removing background-size: 1600px auto? Does your theme use a different css for iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not only an iPhone problem. Try to set the minimum width of your page to 1600 pixels (it's the width of your background image):

```
body {
    min-width: 1600px;
}
```